# My lambda Execution result is done getting queried data in log output

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, microservices, serverless-framework

I have my nodejs lambda function connecting to rds and select data and gives me output in log output. Please help me how to pass parms and get output. My code is attached. My nodejs function connecting to rds but I cannot see mydata in execution result.

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "testdb.ckwywu.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  user: "root",
  password: "mypassword",
  database: "database",
  port: "3306",
 // debug: true
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
 // var sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES (4, 'dfdd')";
var sql = "select * from database.users";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
//    console.log("1 record inserted");
      console.log(result);
      context.succeed("done");
  });
});
//callback("sucess");
}
```

Comment: what are the results you're getting currently?

Comment: Suplemental info, instead of storing your db info like that it would be a better idea to store it in say systems manager parameter store ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html ) and then pull it using the getParameter function in the JS SDK ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#getParameter-property ). That gives you a centralized parameter store that you can also encrypt to keep passwords safer.

Comment: Check out lambda proxy. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-proxy-integration-lambda-function-nodejs

You need pass your results to 

callback(null, {  output: JSON.stringify(result)})

Inputs can be extracted out of event.